# Unexpected behaviour overriding multiple attributes in an object

Tags: scala

If I run the following:

```
trait A {
    val i: Int
}

trait B {
    val j: Int
    val i = j
}

case class C(j: Int) extends B

println(C(3).i)
```

I will get the output I expect of 3 for i. However if I change C for an object thus:

```
object C { val j = 3 }
```

The value I get for i is zero. Is this what I should expect and if so why?

Comment: Where are you using `A`, is it relevant?

Comment: Is `object C` extending **B**?

Comment: Actually, it's strange that `case class` doesn't give 0, because the constructor of `B` should run first before `j` is initialized. I don't see why at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you define `val` in `A` the value `i` is set at *construction* time.

So this works for a `case class` as `j` is in its constructor. But not for the `object` as `i` is already set with the default Int value.

Just change the `val`s to `def`s and it works:

```
  trait B {
    def j: Int
    def i = j
  }
```

As with `def`s, `i` and `j` is evaluated every time.